# junit test for methods calling another method of different class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am writing `Junit` test for the below code using `Mockito` but I am getting a null pointer exception is there a mistake in the way I'm mocking it?

```
public boolean isApplyChecked()
{
    return _rranalysis.getApplytoAllState();
}
```

and my test case is

```
@Test
public void testIsApplyChecked() {
    JCheckBox Rra_Apply_Field = Mockito.mock(JCheckBox.class);
    Mockito.when(Rra_Apply_Field.isSelected()).thenReturn(true);
    RepeatRejectAnalysis rs  = Mockito.mock(RepeatRejectAnalysis.class);
    Mockito.when(rs.getApplytoAllState()).thenReturn(true);
    boolean val = repeatRejectAnalysis_Listener.isApplyChecked();

    Assert.assertEquals(true, val);     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject the `RepeatRejectAnalysis` class dependency into your `repeatRejectAnalysis_Listener`. For example:

**Use setter**

```
RepeatRejectAnalysis rs =Mockito.mock(RepeatRejectAnalysis.class);
Mockito.when(rs.getApplytoAllState()).thenReturn(true);
repeatRejectAnalysis_Listener.setAnalysis(rs);
boolean val=repeatRejectAnalysis_Listener.isApplyChecked();
```

**Use @InjectMocks**

```
public class ListenerTest{

   @InjectMocks
   private Listener repeatRejectAnalysis_Listener = new Listener();

   @Mock
   private RepeatRejectAnalysis rs;

   @Before
   public void init(){
      MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(this);
   }

   // reuse the exact same method as you have now.
   @Test
   public void testIsApplyChecked() {
    JCheckBox Rra_Apply_Field=Mockito.mock(JCheckBox.class);
    Mockito.when(Rra_Apply_Field.isSelected()).thenReturn(true);
    RepeatRejectAnalysis rs =Mockito.mock(RepeatRejectAnalysis.class);
    Mockito.when(rs.getApplytoAllState()).thenReturn(true);
    boolean val=repeatRejectAnalysis_Listener.isApplyChecked();
    Assert.assertEquals(true, val);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct about that one **missing** piece of mocking that you need. But then: **none** of the mocking that you have in your current test case seems to be required.

The idea of tests is to use a (minimal!) setup containing exactly those steps that are really mandatory to **enable** a test.

There is no point in mocking a JCheckBox ... when the method you intend to test doesnt make use of that check box in any way!